# SSH port on Virtual Machine is closed

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, ports

I want to connect to my Arch linux virtual machine from my debian(host) by ssh, but
connection is refused, I scanned 22 port on Virtual Machine and its closed, How can I open this port to enable ssh connection to this virtual machine? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ashlie's answer is correct, but I believe robinloop may have downloaded a recent version of Arch, with systemd installed, in which case the Open SSH server will be started with:

```
sudo systemctl enable sshd
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

You may check whether ssh correctly started by means of

```
sudo systemctl status sshd
```

Exactly because Arch Linux is a light, simple, elegant OS, very little is installed by default, and you will have to add programs as you see fit. Luckily, it is not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to the SSH server not running in the system.Install the open ssh server and try to connect to virtual machine.

To install open ssh in Arch Linux:

> pacman -Sy openssh

Start openssh  daemon  with:

> rc.d start  sshd

if this works , Make  sshd  start with  the  virtual machine.